# Is there any package to write CSS code in React like Material_UI's makeStyles()?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Sometimes I don't want to use Material UI to React Project. But I like Material_UI's **makeStyles** feature to write CSS code in React. Is there any package to write CSS code within the same file like Material_UI's **makeStyles()** feature?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    
  },
});
```

Comment: So you don't want to use Material-UI in your project, but you'll need it installed as a dev dependency anyway to be able to use MUI's `makeStyles` utility? Is this correct or am I missing something? Have you tried [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/)? If not, can you explain your use-case a little more clearly with more detail?

Comment: @Drew Reese Yeah, You are right. I never used styled-components.